# Mouselistener not responding on jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouse-listeners

Never before really relied on swings layoutmanagers to do the drawing before when making games so out of curiosity and boredom I set out to do just that. I have simply a matrix of buttons with different colors set up on a panel with the idea being that later on the buttons will open and show an animal you have to shoot.

The problem is that the mouselistener I add to one of the jpanels does not respond to clicks on the buttons (or anywhere else within the frame) but only on the borders of the frame when the frame is resized so there is a black area visible.

The listener (doesn't do much but add listener to Board).

```
public class Game implements MouseListener {
JFrame frame;
Board board;

public Game() {
    this.frame = new JFrame("Shoot a Tile");
    this.board = new Board(20, 20);
    this.board.addMouseListener(this);
    this.frame.getContentPane().add(board);
    this.frame.pack();
    this.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.frame.setVisible(true);
    this.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Game();
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("HELLO I WAS CLICKED AT: " + e.getPoint());

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("HELLO I ENTERED AT: " + e.getPoint());

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("HELLO I EXITED AT: " + e.getPoint());

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("HELLO I WAS PRESSED AT: " + e.getPoint());

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("HELLO I WAS RELEASED AT: " + e.getPoint());

}
```

The board

```
public class Board extends JPanel {

private Tile[][] tiles;
private int row, column;
public static final Random rnd = new Random();

public Board(int row, int column) {
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
    this.tiles = new Tile[row][column];
    setBackground(Color.black);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(row, column));
    setTiles();
}

private void setTiles() {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        Color color = new Color(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),
                rnd.nextInt(256));
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            tiles[i][j] = new Tile(color);
            add(tiles[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The tile

```
public class Tile extends JButton {

private Color color;
private List<Particle> particles;
private int x, y, width, height;
private boolean destroyed;

public Tile(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}

@Override
@Transient
public Color getBackground() {
    return color;
}

public void destroy() {
    this.destroyed = true;
}

public boolean isDestroyed() {
    return destroyed;
}

@Override
@Transient
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(50, 40);
}}
```

The code is pretty simple even if it is on many lines, shortest possible SSCEE.

Comment: I would say that the `JButton`s are consuming you mouse events...

Comment: Is that how it works on swing/awt? The component on the foreground consumes it even if the listener was added to the container?

Comment: Was really hoping to avoid drawing the tiles myself in the paintcomponent override of the jpanel which is really no step away from active rendering...damn you swing! I suppose I could add the listener to every button on the panel..

Comment: There is away, but it's really messy.  Check out [`Toolkit#addAWTEventListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener%28java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,%20long%29), which allows you to register a listener for different types of events passing through the event queue.  It's messy, cause you will receive ALL the events, not just those targeted at a given component.  May still need to be some manipulation of the point information to translate it to the correct coordinate space, but it can be done.  It might end up been simpler to do the custom paint..

Comment: Create one listener, add it to all the buttons, have it invoke its (UI) parent listener.

Comment: Curious why you want the JPanel to consume the events, and not the buttons themselves?  It would be easy enough to create an ActionListener (when JButtons are clicked, they create ActionEvents, not MouseEvents), and register it with each button (as suggested by rcook).  The method signature of ActionListener.actionPerformed() gives you a reference to the button, which allows you to vary behavior based on which button was pressed.  If you need the mouse coordinates, register a MouseListener on your JFrame's GlassPane, which you can get a reference to via JFrame.getGlassPane().